Face Project is not working
I'm sculpting the donut icing. I turned on Snapping > Face Project, and I applied subdivision.
However, the icing still looks like this. I wonder if there's anything I've done wrong?

You show your snapping options, but not what you do with them. What exactly isn't working?

Hello! I am making the icing of a donut, but once I move one vertex, the other vertices also disapear into the donut (not snapping to the donut surface). So I am confused about why"Snapping Face Project" isn't working~

This snapping system is an option applied to operators such as move, rotate or scale. They are not available in Sculpt mode.
And there is no need to apply subdivision for snapping to work (in fact, it makes it harder to use since you have more vertices to work with). You should leave the modifier at the end of your modifiers pile.
For what you try to do, I would advise the following:

Select your icing object and ↹ Tab into Edit mode to edit its mesh.
In the Proportional Editing, enable "Connected Only". You can either enable proportional editing right there too, or toggle it on/off while using tools by holding down O. This will allow you to  smoothly and proportionally edit multiple vertices in one go without having to manually edit all of them one by one. You can change the radius of effect with the mousewheel.

Similarly for snapping, you can enable it by default, but also toggle it on/off by holding down ⎈ Ctrl while using a tool.
You can use the move tool to place the vertices on the target surface:

As you can see, it snaps the vertices on the surface, but the mesh doesn't magically appear on top of the surface to look like an icing. But it's simply doing what you ask. To circumvent that, you could add a Displace modifier before the subdivision:

You will probably need to adapt the strength. I also advise toggling on all visibility toggles of the displace modifier, while the subdivision modifier have only its cage disabled. This way, you can netter see and control what you are doing in edit mode.



wow! Thank you so much! Sorry for replying so late.

you helped me alot!

My pleasure. While thank comments are always appreciated, it really helps the website and the users to upvote the post that helped you. If you feel it completely solved your issue, consider marking it as accepted.
